# get the indexes of all values that answer a filter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains floats and I want to get all the indexes of cells that match a certain filter.

So let's say I have this DataFrame:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.7 | 0.9 |
| B | 0.7 | 1 | 0.3 |
| C | 0.9 | 0.3 | 1 |

And my filter is >=0.9
I want to get the indexes (0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(0,2),(2,0).

Or to make it even more specific, I have the pearson correlation data frame and I want to get all the columns that have a correlation bigger than 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argwhere()`:

```
import numpy as np
out=np.argwhere(df.to_numpy()>=0.9).tolist()
```

output of `out`:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: It gives back an empty list. As you can see in this [link](https://i.imgur.com/BI9WXG7.png) screenshot I get an empty list even tho I should get at least [41,41] since it's 1.0

Comment: @Matrucci yeah I see try `np.argwhere(df.to_numpy()>=0.9).tolist()` or if again you are grtting empty list then post the output of `df.tail()`

Comment: yes thank you so much! I got that working now